# How to import data in csv format in J?

Tags: j

I want to know how can I import data in CSV and then how I can deal with it?

I had loaded the file but do not know how to read it.

```
'',' fixdsv dat ] load '/Users/apple/Downloads/data'
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the file `/Users/apple/Downloads/data` is a csv file then you should be able to load it into a J session as a boxed table like this:

```
load 'csv'
data=: readcsv '/Users/apple/Downloads/data'
```

If the file uses delimiters other than commas (e.g. Tabs) then you could use the `tables/dsv` addon.

```
data=: TAB readdsv '/Users/apple/Downloads/data'
```

See the J wiki for more information on the [tables/csv](http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Addons/tables/csv) and [tables/dsv](http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Addons/tables/dsv) addons.

Answer (score 1):

After loading the file, I think that I would start by reading the file into a variable then working with that.

```
data=: 1:!1 <'filepath/filename' NB. filename and path need to be boxed string
```

http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/dx001.htm

Also you could look at jd which is specifically a relational database system if you are more focussed on file management than data processing.

http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Jd/Index